# Kaluza's law and Beowulf.64b

Tags: historical-linguistics, poetry, old-english

**in short :**

- (1) how shall I scan Beowulf.64b "herespēd ġyfen" ?
- (2) How shall I understand [Seiichi Suzuki](http://kansaigaidai.academia.edu/SeiichiSuzuki)'s remark about 64b :

> "[a verse whose] second lift fails to be occupied by a sequence of a
>   short stressed syllable and a following syllable through suspension of
>   resolution : e.g. 64b [... and] 2912b" (in [The Metrical Organization of Beowulf: Prototype and Isomorphism](https://www.academia.edu/10718739/The_Metrical_Organization_of_Beowulf_Prototype_and_Isomorphism), 8.1.3; p. 342)

---

**full details :**

I read in this account of the [Kaluza's law](https://www.heorot.dk/kaluza-dating-txt.html#a3n4) that

> [in Beowulf, Kaluza's law] applies regularly [... in] verse-finally under primary stress in
>   Bliss's verse types 2A1b [...]

So let's have a look at [Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf).64b, [one of the verses concerned by Kaluza's law](https://www.heorot.dk/kaluza-dating-txt.html#a).

> herespēd ġyfen

This verse is analyzed [here](https://www.heorot.dk/kaluza-dating-txt.html#a) as a (Bliss) 2A3b verse and a (Hutcheson) 1rAn [pxSpx] verse.

I'm not sure to understand what's behind [pxSpx] : is its something like /herespēd *caesura* /ġyfen ? Seiichi Suzumi describes 64b as a Sievers' "A1s" verse ([The Metrical Organization of Beowulf: Prototype and Isomorphism](https://www.academia.edu/10718739/The_Metrical_Organization_of_Beowulf_Prototype_and_Isomorphism), p. 498) and adds the following remark about 64b :

> "[a verse whose] second lift fails to be occupied by a sequence of a
>   short stressed syllable and a following syllable through suspension of
>   resolution : e.g. 64b [... and] 2912b" (in [The Metrical Organization of Beowulf: Prototype and Isomorphism](https://www.academia.edu/10718739/The_Metrical_Organization_of_Beowulf_Prototype_and_Isomorphism), 8.1.3; p. 342)

So,

- (1) how shall I scan Beowulf.64b "herespēd ġyfen" ?
- (2) how shall I understand [Seiichi Suzuki](http://kansaigaidai.academia.edu/SeiichiSuzuki)'s remark about 64b ?